# how to time an arbitrary function in f#

Tags: function, f#, lambda

here's the problem. I need to time a function in f# using another function. I have this piece of code

```
let time f a =
  let start = System.DateTime.Now in
  let res = (fun f a -> f(a)) in
  let finish = System.DateTime.Now in
  (res, finish - start)
```

which I'm trying to call saying

```
time ackermann (2,9);;
```

I have a function ackermann that takes a tuple (s,n) as argument
Probably something fundamentally wrong with this but I don't think I'm far away from a solution that could and looks somewhat like this.

Any suggestions?

Oh btw. the error message I'm getting is saying :

stdin(19,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : (('_a -> '_b) -> '_a -> '_b) * System.TimeSpan
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Comment: It's not related to your question, but [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) is a wellknown example of a total computable but not primitive recursive function. Measuring running time of this function is a bad idea :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have at least two issues:

1. Try `let res = f a`.  You already have values `f` and `a` in scope, but you're currently defining `res` as a function which takes a new `f` and applies it to a new `a`.
2. Don't use `DateTime`s (which are appropriate for representing dates and times, but not short durations).  Instead, you should be using a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

Comment: This will work for all functions? I mean, what about if `f` function has 2 or 3 parametters? maybe my question is stupid, but i'm new with F# and functional programming

Comment: @Tom - if the arguments are in a tuple (like `f (1,2)`), then this will work, but if the arguments are curried (like `f 1 2`) then you'd need to write a separate version of the timing function.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
let time f =
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
  let r = f()
  sw.Stop()
  printfn "%O" sw.Elapsed
  r
```

Usage

```
time (fun () -> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100))
```

I usually keep the following in my code files when sending a bunch of stuff to fsi.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#time "on"
#endif
```

That turns on fsi's built-in timing, which provides more than just execution time:

```
Real: 00:00:00.099, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Comment: What about if `f` function has some parametters... I mean, i can do something like `time Fibonacci 23`?

Comment: @Tom: You'll need to use a lambda: `time (fun () -> Fibonacci 23)`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
let time f = fun a ->
    let start = System.DateTime.Now
    let res = f a
    (res, System.DateTime.Now - start)
```

You can then use it to create timed functions e.g.

```
let timedAckermann = time ackermann
let (res, period) = timedAckermann (2,9)
```

You should also consider using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for timing instead of `DateTime`s.

Comment: okay that is quite smart too. could you elaborate on why this would be preferable to 

    let time f a =
        let start = System.DateTime.Now
        let res = f a
        (res, System.DateTime.Now - start)
?
hmm can't seem to make it look like code in comments :p

Comment: @PNS - Your version is essentially the same, and is probably preferable to my answer - mine is just explicit about returning a function which is implicit in your version.

Answer (score 1):

As was already suggested, you should use Stopwatch instead of DateTime for this kind of timing analyses.

What wasn't mentioned yet is that if you for some reason need to use DateTime, then always consider using DateTime.UtcNow rather than DateTime.Now. The implementation of DateTime.Now can be paraphrased as "DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()", and that "ToLocalTime()" part is doing more than you might think it would do. In addition to having less overhead, DateTime.UtcNow also avoids headaches related to daylight savings time. You can find several articles and [blog posts](http://www.keyvan.ms/the-darkness-behind-datetime-now) on the web on the differences between DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by how FSharp Interactive does it (see https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L175), this will time the function plus report how much CPU, allocation, etc.

Example output: `Real: 00:00:00.2592820, CPU: 00:00:26.1814902, GC gen0: 30, gen1: 1, gen2: 0`

```
  
  let time f =
      let ptime = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
      let numGC = System.GC.MaxGeneration
      let startTotal = ptime.TotalProcessorTime
      let startGC = [| for i in 0 .. numGC -> System.GC.CollectionCount(i) |]
      let stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
      let res = f ()
      stopwatch.Stop()
      let total = ptime.TotalProcessorTime - startTotal
      let spanGC = [ for i in 0 .. numGC-> System.GC.CollectionCount(i) - startGC.[i] ]
      let elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed 
      printfn "Real: %A, CPU: %A, GC %s" elapsed total ( spanGC |> List.mapi (sprintf "gen%i: %i") |> String.concat ", ")
    res
```